# Laravel 4 - dynamic configuration

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel 4 and I need to set some database queries in configuration files. For example:

```
config/prod/queries.php
config/stage/qieries.php
```

And I want to call them like

```
DB::connection ( 'mysql' )->select ( Config::get('queries.test'););
```

The case is that my query has some params and some filters. For example:

```
 select * from table where some_date between '$today' and '$tomorrow'
```

And if I just put this query in the config files and call it, of course exception for unknown variables `$today` and `$tomorrow` occures.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 1):

In your configuration file

```
            return array(
               "query1"=> "select * from table where some_date between ? and ?"
            );
```

In your program,e.g controller

```
            $query = Config::get("query")['query1'];
            $result = DB::select($query,array("1970-01-01","2014-01-01"));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this approach:

config file:

```
return [
  "select:logs-between-dates" => "select * from logs where date between ? and ?",
  "select:logs-not-between-dates" => "select * from logs where date not between ? and ?"
];
```

class that extends DB logic:

```
class Query extends DB {
  public static $queries = [];

  public static function select($name, $params = []) {
    return self::select(self::$queries['select:'.$name], $params);
  }
}
```

initialization:

```
Query::$queries = Config::get("query");
```

usage:

```
$result = Query::select('logs-between-dates', ["1970-01-01","2014-01-01"]);
```